# Receiving an error from a legacy stored procedure in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I have inherited in my current company. It is used to create an event ID column that allows another stored procedure to bulk upload sales data to those events. (Event ID is the primary key for the tables) I have used this procedure about 10 weeks in a row wih no error and something appears to have broken. I have tried various solutions including trying old files, importing a portion of the file, making more space in the DB, changing the import file type to every type imaginable. This is the error I get Bulk load:

```
<<There are inconsistencies in the data, certain records cannot be resolved, see errors in results>>
```

This appears to be a user defined error.  I believe it has to do with duplicate values but that doesnt make sense.  The results spit back duplicated events but they are not duplicated the input text file.

Here is a sample text file, Tab seperated:

```
    EOS Start   EOS End Event Start Date    Event End Date  Show    Venue   Market/City Ticketing System    Pref. Seating   Cascading Activated Blue Box    BO Form Sent    Event ID    Agency  Management  Sponsorship Source 1    Sponsorship Type    Phone   Internet    BO  IVR URL Notes   # of performances   ticket limit    BB EOS Quanity  Gold EOS Quanity    Plat EOS Quanity    Cent EOS Quanity     PL1     PL2     PL3     PL4     PL5     PL6     PL7     PL8 
8/19/2021   8/26/2021   4/5/2022    4/5/2022    Ben Platt   Frost Amphitheater  Stanford, CA    AXS.com yes     yes         Momentum    CAA AEG Marketing                           1                                                   
8/19/2021   8/26/2021   3/13/2022   3/13/2022   Ben Platt   Masonic Temple Theatre  Detroit, MI AXS.com yes     yes         Momentum    CAA AEG Marketing                           1                                                   
8/19/2021   8/26/2021   3/28/2022   3/28/2022   Ben Platt   Maverik Center  Salt Lake City, UT  Ticketmaster    yes     yes         Momentum    CAA AEG Marketing                           1                                                   
8/19/2021   8/26/2021   3/8/2022    3/8/2022    Ben Platt   Petersen Events Center  Pittsburgh, PA  Ticketmaster    yes     yes         Momentum    CAA AEG Marketing                           1                                                   
8/19/2021   8/26/2021   4/6/2022    4/6/2022    Ben Platt   Santa Barbara Bowl  Santa Barbara, CA   AXS.com yes     yes         Momentum    CAA AEG Marketing                           1                                                   
8/19/2021   8/26/2021   3/18/2022   3/18/2022   Ben Platt   Target Center   Minneapolis, MN AXS.com yes     yes         Momentum    CAA AEG Marketing                           1                                                   
8/19/2021   8/26/2021   4/2/2022    4/2/2022    Ben Platt   The Theater at Virgin Hotels    Las Vegas, NV   AXS.com yes     yes         Momentum    CAA AEG Marketing                           1                                                   
8/19/2021   8/26/2021   3/25/2022   3/25/2022   Ben Platt   Verizon Theatre at Grand Prairie    Grand Prairie, TX   AXS.com yes     yes         Momentum    CAA AEG Marketing                           1                                                   
8/19/2021   8/26/2021   3/19/2022   3/19/2022   Ben Platt   Wintrust Arena  Chicago, IL Ticketmaster    yes     yes         Momentum    CAA AEG Marketing                           1                                                   
8/19/2021   8/26/2021   2/28/2022   2/28/2022   Ben Platt   The Fabulous Fox Theatre    Atlanta, GA Paciolan    yes     yes         Momentum    CAA AEG Marketing                           1                                                   
8/19/2021   8/26/2021   3/16/2022   3/16/2022   Ben Platt   Fabulous Fox Theatre (St. Louis)    St. Louis, MO   Paciolan    yes     yes         Momentum    CAA AEG Marketing                           1
```

Here is the full procedure

```
USE [axp]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[import_event_file]    Script Date: 05/21/2018 14:13:40 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[import_event_file]
(   @file varchar(MAX)
)
as
begin
    create table #get_header_row
    (
        header_row varchar(MAX)
    )
    declare @sql nvarchar(2000);
    set @file = N'C:\Documents and Settings\RyanLatini\My Documents\'+@file;
    set @sql = N'
        BULK INSERT #get_header_row FROM
            ''' + @file + N'''
        WITH
        (
            FIRSTROW = 1,
            LASTROW = 1,
            ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
        );';
    exec(@sql);
    declare @header_row as varchar(max)
    select @header_row = header_row from #get_header_row;
    declare @start_pos as bigint
    set @start_pos = 0
    declare @next_tab_pos as bigint
    declare @curr_field as varchar(255)
    set @sql = N'create table tempconv.dbo.temp_event_load
('
        
    while(charindex(char(9),@header_row,@start_pos)>0)
    begin
        set @next_tab_pos = charindex(char(9),@header_row,@start_pos)
        
        set @curr_field = substring(@header_row,@start_pos,@next_tab_pos-@start_pos)
        if(@curr_field <> '') 
        begin
            set @sql = @sql + N'
    ['+@curr_field+N'] VARCHAR(MAX),'
        end
        set @start_pos = @next_tab_pos + 1
    end
    set @sql = left(@sql,len(@sql)-1)
    set @sql = @sql + N'
)'
    exec(@sql);
    set @sql = N'
        BULK INSERT tempconv.dbo.temp_event_load FROM
            ''' + @file + N'''
            WITH
            (   
                FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\t'',
                FIRSTROW = 2,
                ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
            )'
    exec(@sql);
    alter table tempconv.dbo.temp_event_load add temp_event_load_id int identity(1,1);
    if(exists
        (
            select 
                [name]
            from 
                tempconv.sys.syscolumns 
            where 
                id in (select id from tempconv.sys.sysobjects where [name]='temp_event_load')
                and [name] not in (select import_field from tempconv.dbo.field_mapping)
        )
    )
    begin
        insert into tempconv.dbo.field_mapping (import_field)
        select 
            [name]
        from 
            tempconv.sys.syscolumns 
        where 
            id in (select id from tempconv.sys.sysobjects where [name]='temp_event_load')
            and [name] not in (select import_field from tempconv.dbo.field_mapping)
        raiserror (N'<<%s>>', -- Message id.
            10, -- Severity,
            1, -- State,
            N'Unknown fields in this import, please update field_mapping table with correct values'); -- First argument supplies the string.
    end
    else
    begin
        /* Generate Dynamic SQL for import */
        declare @insert_var varchar(max)
        declare @select_var varchar(max)
        declare @from_var varchar(max)
        declare @where_var varchar(max)
        set @insert_var = ''
        set @from_var = ''
        set @where_var = '';
        /* Generate Insert SQL */
        WITH generate_insert_list (colorder, insert_field) AS
        (
            select 1, cast('' as VARCHAR(MAX))
            union all
            select b.colorder + 1, b.insert_field +  '  ' + a.insert_field + ',
' 
            from ( /*And the above query will return*/
                select 
                    row_number() over (order by tempconv_syscolumns.colorder) as rn,
                    field_mapping.axp_event_field as insert_field
                from 
                    tempconv.dbo.field_mapping
                    inner join tempconv.sys.syscolumns tempconv_syscolumns on
                        field_mapping.import_field = tempconv_syscolumns.name
                    inner join tempconv.sys.sysobjects tempconv_sysobjects on
                        tempconv_syscolumns.id = tempconv_sysobjects.id
                    inner join (
                        select
                            syscolumns.*
                        from
                            axp.sys.syscolumns
                            inner join axp.sys.sysobjects on
                                syscolumns.id = sysobjects.id
                        where
                            sysobjects.name = 'event'
                    ) axp_syscolumns on
                        field_mapping.axp_event_field = axp_syscolumns.name
                where
                    tempconv_sysobjects.name = 'temp_event_load'
            ) a
            INNER JOIN generate_insert_list b ON a.rn = b.colorder
        )

        select 
            top 1 
            @insert_var = left(insert_field,len(insert_field)-3)
        from
            generate_insert_list
        order by
            colorder desc
        /* Generate select list */
        ;WITH generate_select_list (colorder, select_field) AS
        (
            select 1, cast('' as VARCHAR(MAX))
            union all
            select b.colorder + 1, b.select_field +  '  ' + a.select_field + ',
' 
            from ( /*And the above query will return*/
                select 
                    row_number() over (order by tempconv_syscolumns.colorder) as rn,
                    cast(case when field_mapping.axp_related_table is null then
                        case axp_syscolumns.xtype
                            when 61 then 'convert(datetime,temp_event_load.['+field_mapping.import_field+'])'
                            when 56 then 'case when convert(int,replace(replace(temp_event_load.['+field_mapping.import_field+'],char(9),''''),'','',''''))=0 then null else convert(int,replace(temp_event_load.['+field_mapping.import_field+'],char(9),'''')) end'
                            when 104 then 'case when lower(['+field_mapping.import_field+']) in (''yes'',''y'',''true'',''t'',''1'') then 1 else 0 end'
                            when 108 then 'case when convert(real,rtrim(ltrim(replace(replace(temp_event_load.['+field_mapping.import_field+'],char(9),''''),''$'',''''))))=0 then null else convert(real,rtrim(ltrim(replace(replace(temp_event_load.['+field_mapping.import_field+'],char(9),''''),''$'','''')))) end'
                            when 167 then 'cast(['+field_mapping.import_field+'] as VARCHAR('+case when axp_syscolumns.length=-1 then 'MAX' else cast(axp_syscolumns.length as varchar(255)) end +'))' 
        
                        end
                    else
                        case when charindex(' ',reverse(field_mapping.axp_related_table))>1 
                            then right(field_mapping.axp_related_table,charindex(' ',reverse(field_mapping.axp_related_table))-1)
                            else field_mapping.axp_related_table
                        end+'.'+field_mapping.axp_related_table_field
                    end + ' as '+ field_mapping.axp_event_field as VARCHAR(MAX)) as select_field
                from 
                    tempconv.dbo.field_mapping
                    inner join tempconv.sys.syscolumns tempconv_syscolumns on
                        field_mapping.import_field = tempconv_syscolumns.name
                    inner join tempconv.sys.sysobjects tempconv_sysobjects on
                        tempconv_syscolumns.id = tempconv_sysobjects.id
                    inner join (
                        select
                            syscolumns.*
                        from
                            axp.sys.syscolumns
                            inner join axp.sys.sysobjects on
                                syscolumns.id = sysobjects.id
                        where
                            sysobjects.name = 'event'
                    ) axp_syscolumns on
                        field_mapping.axp_event_field = axp_syscolumns.name
                where
                    tempconv_sysobjects.name = 'temp_event_load'
            ) a
            INNER JOIN generate_select_list b ON a.rn = b.colorder
        )
        select 
            top 1 
            @select_var = left(select_field,len(select_field)-3)
        from
            generate_select_list
        order by
            colorder desc
        /* Generate from list */
        ;WITH generate_from_list (colorder, from_field) AS
        (
            select 1, cast('' as VARCHAR(MAX))
            union all
            select b.colorder + 1, b.from_field +  '    ' + a.from_field + ',
' 
            from ( /*And the above query will return*/
                select 
                    row_number() over (order by tempconv_syscolumns.colorder) as rn,
                    'axp.dbo.'+ field_mapping.axp_related_table as from_field
                from 
                    tempconv.dbo.field_mapping
                    inner join tempconv.sys.syscolumns tempconv_syscolumns on
                        field_mapping.import_field = tempconv_syscolumns.name
                    inner join tempconv.sys.sysobjects tempconv_sysobjects on
                        tempconv_syscolumns.id = tempconv_sysobjects.id
                where
                    tempconv_sysobjects.name = 'temp_event_load' and
                    field_mapping.axp_related_table is not null
            ) a
            INNER JOIN generate_from_list b ON a.rn = b.colorder
        )

        select 
            top 1 
            @from_var = '   tempconv.dbo.temp_event_load,
'+left(from_field,len(from_field)-3)
        from
            generate_from_list
        order by
            colorder desc
        /* Generate where variable */
        ;WITH generate_where_list (colorder, where_field) AS
        (
            select 1, cast('' as VARCHAR(MAX))
            union all
            select b.colorder + 1, b.where_field +  '   ' + a.where_field + ' and
' 
            from (
                select 
                    row_number() over (order by tempconv_syscolumns.colorder) as rn,
                    field_mapping.axp_related_query as where_field
                from 
                    tempconv.dbo.field_mapping
                    inner join tempconv.sys.syscolumns tempconv_syscolumns on
                        field_mapping.import_field = tempconv_syscolumns.name
                    inner join tempconv.sys.sysobjects tempconv_sysobjects on
                        tempconv_syscolumns.id = tempconv_sysobjects.id
                where
                    tempconv_sysobjects.name = 'temp_event_load' and
                    field_mapping.axp_related_query is not null
            ) a
            INNER JOIN generate_where_list b ON a.rn = b.colorder
        )

        select 
            top 1 
            @where_var = left(where_field,len(where_field)-6)
        from
            generate_where_list
        order by
            colorder desc
        /* Load prep_table to verify data accuracy */
        print 'select
    temp_event_load.temp_event_load_id,
'+@select_var+' into tempconv.dbo.temp_event_prep
from
'+@from_var+'
where
'+@where_var
        exec('select
    temp_event_load.temp_event_load_id,
'+@select_var+' into tempconv.dbo.temp_event_prep
from
'+@from_var+'
where
'+@where_var)
        /* Check to make sure all records are accounted for */
        declare @insert bit
        set @insert = 1
        if(exists(
            select 
                temp_event_load_id
            from
                tempconv.dbo.temp_event_load
            where
                temp_event_load_id not in (
                    select
                        temp_event_load_id
                    from
                        tempconv.dbo.temp_event_prep
                )
        ))
        begin
            raiserror (N'<<%s>>', -- Message id.
                10, -- Severity,
                1, -- State,
                N'Not all records matched properly, please verify data accuracy before loading, see errors in results'); -- First argument supplies the string.
            select 
                *
            from
                tempconv.dbo.temp_event_load
            where
                temp_event_load_id not in (
                    select
                        temp_event_load_id
                    from
                        tempconv.dbo.temp_event_prep
                )
            set @insert = 0;
        end
        /* Check against duplicate records */
        if(exists(
            select
                temp_event_load_id
            from
                tempconv.dbo.temp_event_prep
            group by
                temp_event_load_id
            having
                count(*)>1
        ))
        begin
            raiserror (N'<<%s>>', -- Message id.
                10, -- Severity,
                1, -- State,
                N'There are inconsistencies in the data, certain records cannot be resolved, see errors in results'); -- First argument supplies the string.
            select * from tempconv.dbo.temp_event_prep order by temp_event_load_id
            select
                temp_event_load_id
            from
                tempconv.dbo.temp_event_load
            where
                temp_event_load_id in (
                    select
                        temp_event_load_id
                    from
                        tempconv.dbo.temp_event_prep
                    group by
                        temp_event_load_id
                    having
                        count(*)>1
                )
            set @insert = 0;
        end
        if(@insert = 1)
        begin
            CREATE TABLE #inserted_ids (
                event_id bigint
            );
            exec('insert into axp.dbo.event
(
'+@insert_var+'
) OUTPUT inserted.event_id INTO #inserted_ids
select
'+@select_var+'
from
'+@from_var+'
where
'+@where_var);
            select
                event_id,
                artist,
                venue,
                market,
                fulfillment_co,
                CONVERT(varchar(10),event_start_date,101) event_start_date,
                CONVERT(varchar(10),event_end_date,101) event_end_date,
                CONVERT(varchar(10),eos_start_date,101) eos_start_date,
                CONVERT(varchar(10),eos_end_date,101) eos_end_date
            from
                event_view
            where
                event_id in (select event_id from #inserted_ids)
            order by
                eos_start_date
        end
        update event set bb_eos_tix_qty = 0 where bb_eos_tix_qty is null
        update event set gold_eos_tix_qty = 0 where gold_eos_tix_qty is null
        update event set plat_eos_tix_qty = 0 where plat_eos_tix_qty is null
        update event set cent_eos_tix_qty = 0 where cent_eos_tix_qty is null
        update event set bb_allot_tix_qty = 0 where bb_allot_tix_qty is null
        update event set gold_allot_tix_qty = 0 where gold_allot_tix_qty is null
        update event set plat_allot_tix_qty = 0 where plat_allot_tix_qty is null
        update event set cent_allot_tix_qty = 0 where cent_allot_tix_qty is null
        update event set vip_allot_tix_qty = 0 where vip_allot_tix_qty is null
        update event set bio_allot_tix_qty = 0 where bio_allot_tix_qty is null
        update event set prem_allot_tix_qty = 0 where prem_allot_tix_qty is null
        update event set share_shift_tix_qty = 0 where share_shift_tix_qty is null
        update event set other_tix_qty = 0 where other_tix_qty is null
    end
    drop table tempconv.dbo.temp_event_load
    drop table tempconv.dbo.temp_event_prep
end
```

Comment: *Careful* that SQL is an injection nightmare.

Comment: @Larnu can you elaborate?  Not the best with SQL Programming

Comment: You're blindly concatenating an up to 2 billion character string into a dynamic statement without sanitising the value. I suggest Googling SQL Injection to fully understand the severity of the problem.

Comment: @larnu regardless of the SQL Injection issue..... can you help me understand why I am getting my error?

Comment: Sample data will go a long way here

Comment: @squillman added in sample text file data

Comment: Looks like there's a tab before your first column header; that'll be a problem.

Comment: @Larnu for some reason that is the way this procedure is set up.

Comment: I'm talking about the file, not the procedure. And that tab will be inferred as a delimiter.

Comment: @Larnu yes I know you are....for whatever reason it doesnt run without that tab.  This procedure has worked for 10 weeks of me managing it and for 2 years prior.  Always with the leading tab delim on the header.  I don't understand why its set up that  way but again I inherited this SP and just need to it to run.

Comment: You can add an errorfile option to bulk insert ..... WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', LASTROW = 1, MAXERRORS = 100,   ERRORFILE = 'C:\ETL\.....\daily_20180101_log')